# How to write a regular expression for specific string?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am writing a program to locate the gene. `1..789` is the start and end position of the gene 5'-3'. The complement `(45678..98765)` are the gene 3'-5'. So the start of the gene is `98765` and end at `45678`.

I would like to extract the data and store in the list of python in the format of `["None",1,789]` and `["complement',98765,45678]` repectively.

1. `1..789`  => `["None",1,789]`
2. `complement(45678..98765)` => `["complement',98765,45678]`

Am I going to use regular expression and how to write?

Beside regular expression, is there any other method?

Comment: What are you trying to get? explain the regular expresion you need

Comment: Question is not clear.

Comment: I am writing a program to locate the gene. 1..789 is the start and end position of the gene  5'-3'. The complement (45678..98765) are the gene 3'-5'. so the start of the gene is 98765 and end at 45678. I would like to extract the data and store in the list of python in the format of ["None",1,789] and ["complement',98765,45678] repectively

Comment: @pythonbeginner updated your quesiton with information from your comment. Please always show, what you have tried already, that others can see where you got stuck, if you have any code and update your question with any new information.

Comment: bobble bubble thank you for your comment. I am as new as even don't know how to start to write except import re and get trouble in there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re

arr = [
    '1..789',
    'complement(45678..98765)',
]

for s in arr:
    print(list(re.search(r'^(.*?)\(?(\d+)\.\.(\d+)', s).groups()))
```

**Output:**

```
['', '1', '789']
['complement', '45678', '98765']
```

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
    (.*?)       # group 1, 0 or more any character, not greedy
    \(?         # optional opening parenthesis
    (\d+)       # group 2, 1 or more digits
    \.\.        # 2 dots
    (\d+)       # group 3, 1 or more digits
```

Comment: consider converting tuples into lists :)

Comment: this is so awesome! Thank you so much.

Comment: Reading the question, it seems OP wants to swap the digits in result if there is a `complement`. Not sure however. @pythonbeginner needs to clarify, if so :)

Comment: @bobblebubble: Yes, but it's not really clear and, well, they've accepted so I guess it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

```
import re
st = "complement(45678..98765)"
pat = re.compile(r'\w+')
result = pat.findall(st)
for element in result:
    if type(element) is int:
        a = result.pop()
        result.remove(element)
        result.append(str(a))
print(result)
```

result:

```
['complement', '45678', '98765']
```

Here `\w` means match alphanumeric characters and in `\w+` The "+" means match one or more occurences of the pattern, better to say... The words.

so `\w+` would match group of those characters you would want such as `'45678'`

```
import re
st = "1..789"
pat = re.compile(r'\w+')
result = pat.findall(st)
for element in result:
    if type(element) is int:
        a = result.pop()
        result.remove(element)
        result.append(str(a))
print(result)
```

result:

```
['1', '789']
```

alphanumberic means: all alphabets from **A TO Z** and all numbers from **0 To 9**

If you are new to regex, consider reading [sams teach yourself regular experssions Book](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/sams-teachyourself/0672325667/)
which has a really great intro to regex and it will give you an eagle-eye-like perspective to the subject.
right after that all of the questions in your head will be answered.

[this website is also a good resource](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

Comment: The result for `1..789` is wrong.

Comment: @Toto, I just copied the output of my editor...

Comment: Thanks Moh. If I would like to have the result ['complement', 98765, 45678], is there way to do that? 98765 and 45678 is an integer instead of string. would you please explain the theory of how to get the result. I am absolutely new to python.

Comment: @pythonbeginner, see my edits seconds later.

Comment: OK, but it's wrong, the first element should be `"None"`

Comment: @Toto, Thanks for feedback , i will edit it.

Comment: thanks Moh, it already a big step for me to go on. Thank you for your help